# Clicking in the horizontal ruler does nothing in Word

Tags: microsoft-word

In Word 16.53 I'm trying to left-align half the text of a line, and right-align the second part. To create layouts like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
| Some something                               Year |
| Normal text beneath unpeturbed by the alignment   |
| tricks or hacks in the line above.                |
|                                                   |
|                                                   |
```

I tried to follow this solution: [SuperUser: Having some text align left and other align right, in same line](https://superuser.com/a/1062392/325613)

So I selected the (as far as I know) right-tab stop symbol using the top-left box of the rulers, and then I clicked in the horizontal ruler along the top at the right-edge of the page (inside the margin).

[image]

However, clicking in the ruler does nothing. No right-tab mark is left there. Pressing tab inside of this line also has regular behaviour.

How can I right-align part of the line only in modern versions of word?

Comment: As per my answer in the linked question-  Click the tab selector at the left end of the ruler until it displays a Right Tab stop. The answer shows what it looks like.

Comment: @DavidPostill that symbol doesn't exist in my version of word. I think that the symbol I've screenshotted is what it looks like nowadays

Comment: So click until the arrow points right as per the other answer

Comment: @DavidPostill that other answer says to click until the arrow points left. I think the right-pointing arrow is the default tabstop.

Comment: OK. When it's pointing left **double-click** in the tab bar.